# Getting correct email set from Parse table

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a view where a user can flip through other user's profiles. The user will have the option to email those users if they wish. The issue I am having is only the email of the first profile is being used.

For example...

Let's say the view has 3 profiles, each has a unique email.

a@gmail.com

b@gmail.com

c@gmail.com

Only a@gmail.com is getting picked up.

Should I store these in an Array and pick them out that way?

Or is another method recommended?

EDIT:

To clarify, I do not want to email every email at once, they need to be unique to the profile the user is looking at.

So if they are looking at Profile C, they need to email only to c@gmail.com.

Here's something I have tried:

```
// Profile Generator Method
- (void)createProfile
{
   // I use a for loop to create each profile
   // in the for loop I set the emails to the array, see below
   [self.emailArray addObject:[self.profileObject objectForKey:@"email"]];

   // add the emailUser method as a target to a button
}

// My Email Method
- (void)emailUser
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.emailArray count]; i++)
    {
        self.emailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.emailArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        [mc setSubject:@"Note"];
        [mc setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.emailString]];

        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device is not configured to send mail." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT TWO:

When I log my emailArray as the profiles are being created I see all emails in the array.

When I get to the emailUser method, only one appears.

Comment: Post some code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent several emails, but separately, using Multiple `MFMailComposeViewController` will not be good option.
Instead you should sent those emails via your own web service. Pass all your email addressees to a Webservice(`PHP`, `DotNet` etc), and it should prepare unique body for every email and send individually.

If you can't use web service, then you should present `MFMailComposeViewController` one after the other in `Queued` model. It will not be a Good User experience that repeatedly presenting MFMailComposeViewController one after the other.

Comment: This loads all emails into the recipients field though. They need to match the profile the user is looking at currently.

Comment: You mean, the email should be sent to all, but individually? Every email should contain only its To address.

Comment: Right, if you are on profile A, only email that person, not every profile email.

Comment: I think, this can be done through a server side scripting. Pass all your addresses to a web service, and service should prepare emails for every profile.

Comment: All the emails are stored on parse.com. I am querying to load the information on each profile card. Each card displays the correct email, I just can't get the recipient to load the correct email when the email button is tapped.